# Funny Behaviour in GWT CellTable?

Tags: java, gwt

I've created a test case of my CellTable issue as a self contained
panel that can easily be imported into any project:

http://pastebin.com/zDLPKUNh

I've also posted this question on Google Groups GWT discussions.

Basically I have two Date class fields in my row model, a startDate
and an endDate. Each Date has two columns in the CellTable (called
batchTable), one to display the actual date (a DatePickerCell) and the
other being a text input cell for the time.

When the FieldUpdater of the startTime or endTime is fired we parse
the value, save the new time and call batchTable.setRowData() with the
updated object and row index.

The problem is that when FieldUpdater is fired, the cells do not
update?

I specifically edited the FieldUpdater of the endTime cell to
be an hour later than what it was set at.

I've checked as best as I can that all the gets and sets of the
respective startDate and endDate are in order, but I'm thinking that
there's something about CellTable I'm not getting.

Apologies if I've missed anything.

I'm running:
GWT 2.3

I've tested it in the latest Chrome and IE9.

Regards,

Julian

Comment: It's been a long time. I think if I remember, we created some work around hack but did not solve the issue directly. It was only for internal tools, not client facing, so it wasn't such an issue. Sorry... :-(

Comment: I am having same issue. This is with GWT 2.6.0 - Did anyone find a solution yet ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [google docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#updating-from-celltable) it should be enough to just change the field in your object and then call

```
cellTable.redraw();
```

in the update() method.

You could also try to call **setRowData** on your ListDataProvider instead of your CellTable.  However calling **setRowData** on the ListDataProvider would probably end up in a call to every added display of the ListDataProvider which would be the same as calling setRowData on the CellTable directly.

Comment: Hi,none of the above works. See: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/1b5e1519d00e41dc

Comment: did you try to update a non-date field and see if the CellTable is refreshed. By this you can check if this is a Date related problem or a general CellTable problem

Comment: The field in question is a TextInputCell, which means it's pretty generic.

Comment: Hmm I don't see why it shouldn't work. Did you try to debug it (step into setRowData) and see if the internal list is updated ?

Comment: It becomes very difficult to understand why it doesn't work because the changes are cached as pending values and then updated at a later stage..(probably on a different browser event).. further, the actual table infrastructure is separated between the Presenter and the Display (MVP) which becomes quite hairy to understand if you didn't write it. Have you tried out the example? You'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. In my case I had [visiblerange](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) set incorrectly. First parameter is index and second parameter is length. Make sure those two are set up correctly. After that the cell table displays correctly. I did not need to call redraw.